# Excel - Extract Data to the right of the seventh space from the right

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to extract a string of text from the 7th space from the right side of a cell.  The reason I cannot use delimiters is because some names have different lengths (i.e. John Smith, John A. Smith, John Smith Jr.).  Two examples of the cells are as follows.  In general, I just want to pull the numbers so I can put them into individual columns.

Thanks.

```
SMITH JOHN 388.58 388.58 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00

SMITH JR DAVID 1,373.71 261.94 19.89 462.50 354.64 274.74 .00
```

Comment: Can we assume that the first instance of a number is where you want to split the cell?

Comment: Just after the name regardless of the format or length of name.

Answer (score 1):

With data in A2 try,

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), 7*LEN(A2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one finds the first number and splits there:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&"1234567890")),999)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read a little differently that you wanted to have the name in one column and each number in a different column.

If you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function you can use the following:

For the name:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))-6))-1)
```

For the numbers:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[last()-7]/following-sibling::*"))
```

If you have the latest versions with **dynamic arrays** you can enter the 2nd formula normally and it will spill over into the adjacent 6 columns.

If you do not, it will need to be entered as an array over the seven column range by

- selecting the first cell
- extending the range 6 columns to the right
- confirming by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option

1] To extract name, in B1 copied down :

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&1/17)-1))
```

2] To extract value to individual cells, in C1 copied across and down :

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(LEN($A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",""))-7+COLUMN(A1))*999,999))
```

or, using FILTERXML function to extract value.

```
=FILTERXML("<a><a>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1," ","</a><a>")&"</a></a>","a/*[last()-7+"&COLUMN(A1)&"]")
```